# How to append a string to the specific line of a text file in python?

Tags: python-2.7, file, file-handling

Here I am having a text file "sample.txt" contains following lines.

**sample.txt**

Hello

START world

Welcome

happy

STOP the car

Here I want to search the line which consisting the string "START" in any of the line in the text file and I want to append "ABRACADABRA" at the end of same line using python.

**Expected output**

Hello

START world ABRACADABRA

Welcome

happy

STOP the car

Help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: What have You tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

This will print to console. Is this what You wanted? Or do You want to wite outpout to a different file?

```
fh = open("sample.txt", "r")

for line in fh:

    if "START" in line:
        print line.rstrip(), " ABRACADABRA"
    else: 
        print line.rstrip()
```